# Show that $x^4 + 4x^3 - 2x^2 - 5$ is irreducible over the rational numbers.

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I need to show that  $$f(x) = x^4 + 4x^3 - 2x^2 - 5$$ is irreducible over the rational numbers.

So was trying to use the **Eisenstein's** criterion, but I can't find such prime number p (I think it doesn't exist). I could possibly show that $f(ax + b)$ is irreducible. Any tips?

Comment: Is there a typo in the title and the question?  Do you intend $...4x^3...$ rather than $...4^3...$?

Comment: fixed that! Tanks!

Comment: The [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) can be used to determine if there are rational roots.  However, if I understand your question correctly, that is inconclusive.  That is, you could (still) have $f(x) = (x^2 + ax + b)(x^2 + cx + d)$ where $a,b,c,d$ are all rational, but $f(x)$ still doesn't have a rational root.  Therefore, as I say, I think the rational root theorem is inconclusive here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polynomial is already irreducible over $\Bbb F_3$, where it is
$$
f=x^4+x^3+x^2+1.
$$
So it is also irreducible over $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Q$.

How is this fourth degree polynomial irreducible over $\Bbb F_3$? Because it doesn't have roots in $\Bbb F_3$ and because it is not a product of two irreducible monic polynomials of degree $2$ over $\Bbb F_3$ as well. This is easy here, because we only have $3$ such candidates: $x^2+1,x^2+x−1$ and $x^2−x−1$.

Comment: I am totally ignorant in this area.  Briefly, what is $\Bbb{F_3}$?

Comment: It is the finite field with $3$ elements. Do you know the mod $p$ irreducibility test? It is a standard result like Eisenstein. It is also called [reduction crtiterion](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Although I'm not familiar with the mod $p$ irreducibility test, I can certainly do research myself.  I've actually never studied Abstract Algebra, believe it or not; I merely occasionally glanced at a few pages now and then.  You have given me more than enough to go on.  It's not really appropriate for you to attempt more; that would constitute your filling the gap.  It's now on me to go thru Abstract Algebra pdf's, which are readily available, and then later post mathSE questions, (if any).

Comment: But what p did you use to get $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 +1$ ?

Comment: No problem, I just wanted to be helpful, so that you can checkmark my answer :) I used $p=3$, so $\Bbb F_3=\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$, that was your first question.

Comment: I think that you may have confused me (i.e. my comments following your answer) with the original poster.

Comment: @user2661923 Yes, I am sorry. But if it was also helpful for you, no problem :)

Comment: @user2661923 I think in order to understand Dietrich's answer it is good to make a clear distinction between two steps. 1. Looking modulo 3 shows the polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$. 2. Irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ implies irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. The first step is easy to follow. If there *were* a decomposition of $f$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ then taking all coefficients mod 3 would yield a decomposition over $\mathbb{F}_3$. If the latter thing does not exist then the first thing cannot exist either. The second step is a completely different general principle attributed to Gauss.

Comment: @Vincent thanks for the help.

Comment: How is the fourth degree polynomial irreducible over F_3? Because it doesn't have roots in F_3?

Comment: @LawrenceMano Because it is not a product of two irreducible monic polynomials of degree $2$ over $\Bbb F_3$ as well. This is easy here, because we only have $3$ such candidates: $x^2+1,x^2+x-1$ and $x^2-x-1$.

Comment: Now it's perfectly correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> I could possibly show that $f(ax + b)$ is irreducible. Any tips?

Yes that works, notice that $f(x-1)=x^4-8x^2+12x-10$ is Eisenstein with respect to $p=2$, hence $f(x)$ is irreducible over rationals.